# Android HTTP request and response

Tags: android, http, xamarin, request, response

I want to send a http post request from a controller when I login on Xamarin.Android. This is my C# code from the *Login_Activity*

```
btn_login_001.Click += (sender, e) =>{
    User user = new User(edit_user_001.Text.ToString(), edit_password_001.Text.ToString());
    User_controller user_controller = new User_controller();
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = user_controller.check_pass_void(user);

    switch (response.Status){
       case 200:
           Console.WriteLine("Status OK");
           break;
       case 404:
           Console.WriteLine("Status Not Found");
           break;
       default:
           Console.WriteLine("Status Other");
           break;
   }
};
```

Also, this is my code from the controller

```
class User_controller {

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> check_pass_void(User user){

    try {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.130:8080/noguiana/usuario/check_pass_void");

        // Convertir el usuario a JSON
        string user_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(user_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        return await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    } catch {
        return null;
    }

  } 
}
```

My error is that `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` is not a simple `HttpResponseMessage`. Xamarin foces me to return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and now I'm on trouble using http methods like status or
desseliarizing my JSON responses.

If I cast, `Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = user_controller.check_pass_void(user);` to `HttpResponseMessage response = (HttpResponseMessage)user_controller.check_pass_void(user);` it give me this massage:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: what is `edit_user_001` and why are you casting it to a `string`?  And please learn to use async/await - there are basic C# concepts, not anything Xamarin is "forcing" on you

Comment: I'm using `edit_user_001` and `edit_password_001` to create my user object. I'm new on programing I'm learning how to use asyc/await.

Comment: I asked what they were, not what they were being used for.  In your previous question they were actually `TextEdit` controls and you were casting them to string, which I pointed out what wrong.  If you are still doing that here then it is still wrong and your code won't work.

Comment: When I use `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` for my request I be force to use `client.PostAsync`

Comment: yes, that is why I suggested you read up on async/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn to use async/await properly

```
// mark the event handler as async
btn_login_001.Click += async (sender, e) =>{

   ...

   // check_pass_void() is async, so you need to await it
   HttpResponseMessage response = await user_controller.check_pass_void(user);

   ...
```